# How to optimize old meshes?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I am working with a very old mesh; actually it is a terrain. I selected a part of it, where the surface of water is. You may think it does not look too good and you may be right as well.

[image]

The surface is like two surfaces on the same plain, so when it comes to render, it looks like this (I highlighted the area of overlap):

[image]

I used disolve faces on this, where this texture was used, but as you may see, it is still two surfaces:

[image]

Sure I could remove faces easier now, but I thought there may be a better way for this. I want to:

- merge the surface into one, preserving the UVs **OR**
- delete one surface (problem here: bigger parts, what I would love to keep are
  sometimes hiding the scattered surface, and I can not select that, to
  delete) **OR**
- optimize this magically, to "just make it work"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Decimate** modifier to optimize the mesh and it should preserve UVs.

1. Select your object in Object mode
2. Add Modifier **Decimate**
3. In the modifier settings, select **Planar** and set a low angle limit (1 degree is enough if your mesh is truly flat).

   [image]
4. Apply the modifier when you're done. Check the face count to see how many polygons you have now.

***Note:** The Decimate modifier affects the whole object*

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work for me: I separated the "water surface" as a new object (with P, selected), then applied decimate modifier with settings on picture (and tried other settings as well), but all I got a lot of holes in the surface, what I did not wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If I see it right, you have a flat area wich you want to optimize.
The easiest way to optimize this region is to delete the faces(I know the UVs get lost, you have to generate it for these faces again).
Select the surrounding Edges.
Then you can use the GridFill tool, wich you can access via the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> menu.(Type in **GridFill**)
Tweak the values until it looks good.

Comment: Thank you, I would use this, but losing UV-s is not good for me. I need the original look.

Comment: Note: GridFill is accessible through CTRL + F menü as well.